# landscape and portrait in split viewController

Tags: ipad, orientation, uisplitviewcontroller, landscape-portrait

I created a split view controller application.  I want to display my buttons and controls in landscape and portrait view differently(only the position).
When I change the orientation to landscape it shows the controls in portrait only.  When I click on the cell in the tableview then it will show in correct position.  What is the reason for that? Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about your question, but what I think you are trying to ask is how to change your view if the screen is in landscape or portrait orientation. Without seeing your code it is hard to tell you exactly how to do it, but the general idea (at least how I do it in my code) is that you want to split your code into two parts one that is in landscape orientation, and one that is in portrait orientation. You can tell the difference by seeing if the screen height is greater than the screen width.

Comment: I am using the code like that. Separate code for landscape and portrait. But i change orientation from portrait to landscape,then it will not load automatically. When I click on the cell on the table view in split view controller,then only it shows landscape mode.